# Is it possible to test for repeating multiplier in residue classes algebra?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose at each step we have two values: $$s_i = a_1a_2...a_i \bmod n = f(x_1)f(x_2)...f(x_i) \bmod n,$$ $$x_{i+1} \in \mathbb Z_n.$$ Is there a way (i.e. such $n$ and $f: \mathbb Z_n \to \mathbb Z_n$), that we can easily test whether $x_{i+1} = x_k$ for some $k \in \{1,..,i\}$?

In other words, I have some combination $s$ of elements of $\mathbb Z_n$ and for each new $x \in \mathbb Z_n$ I want to test whether this combination already contains $x$ having only the current value of $s$.

I've tried constructing such combination from quadratic residues/nonresidues and prime numbers, but I guess I don't have enough experience with number theory.

Comment: One of my tries converged to the problem of testing whether the product of primes $s_i = p_1p_2...p_i \bmod n$ can be tested for divisibility by $p_{i + 1}$. But I haven't succeded at that either.

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding the problem wrong, but say $f(x_1)=0$, then you have no information about the other numbers whatsoever.

Comment: Well, the description I provided was quite abstract. I can actually control which $x$ values I accept, so it can be limited to $\mathbb Z_p^*$ or even $(\mathbb Z_p^*)^2$.

Comment: Then still, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both units (have an inverse) then you lose all information about them once you do $x_1x_2$. Given *any* unit $u$, one could find a $v$ such that $x_1x_2=uv$. I'm afraid the easiest way to test if $x_{i+1}=x_k$ for some $k\in\{1,\cdots,i\}$ is to just check if $x_{i+1}=x_1$, or $x_{i+1}=x_2$, etc.. If this is some programming problem, share some details on that, so we may be able to help you find an alternative solution

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to "roll my own crypto" with an authentication protocol, which allows to non-interactively generate delegated (i.e. they can be used by some other person later) one-time authentication tokens.

Comment: I've created a prototype that uses cryptocurrency network and automatic payouts, but now that I'm actually implementing it, it seems a bit heavyweight, so I'm giving it a second try. The problem is, with blockchain service has an incentive to store a lot of tokens, as they are used to derive signing keys for transactions. Without blockchain, there is no incentive whatsoever to store megabytes of tokens just to make them one-time.